# Assertions on XML response in Karate

Tags: karate

How to apply assertions in such kind of a response in XML.

I have tried to convert this in json first by using

`* json response = response`

But this returns an invalid json when checked via json validator. As I thought converting in JSON and then matching the response will be easier.

** Assertions**

1. Check if first tag is `Resource`.
2. Check `type` is `type1`
3. Check `valueTota`l is `7`
4. Check `/Resource/entry/url` value is `https://myurl1`
5. Check `/Resource/entry/resource/user/identifier/type/coding/code`
   value is `CC`

```
<Resource xmlns="http://myurl">
   <type xmlns="" value="type1"/>
   <valueTotal xmlns="" value="7"/>
   <entry xmlns="">
      <url value="https://myurl1"/>
      <resource>
         <user>
            <id value="123"/>
            <identifier>
               <type>
                  <coding>
                     <system value="http://myurl2"/>
                     <code value="CC"/>
                     <display value="abcedflk"/>
                  </coding>
                  <text value="test"/>
               </type>
               <system value="http://myurl3"/>
               <value value="90204343"/>
            </identifier>
            <patient>
               <reference value="value/new"/>
            </patient>
            <relationship>
               <extension url="http://myurl4">
                  <valueCodeableConcept>
                     <coding>
                        <system value="http://myurl5"/>
                        <code value="xyz"/>
                        <display value="value11111"/>
                     </coding>
                     <text value="value11111"/>
                  </valueCodeableConcept>
               </extension>
            </relationship>
            <name>
               <family value="ABC"/>
               <given value="TEST"/>
               <given value="JON"/>
            </name>
            <gender value="male"/>
            <birthDate value="1990-02-17"/>
         </user>
      </resource>
      <search>
         <mode value="123zbc"/>
      </search>
   </entry>
      <entry xmlns="">
      <url value="https://myurl1"/>
      <resource>
         <user>
            <id value="123"/>
            <identifier>
               <type>
                  <coding>
                     <system value="http://myurl2"/>
                     <code value="CC"/>
                     <display value="abcedflk"/>
                  </coding>
                  <text value="test"/>
               </type>
               <system value="http://myurl3"/>
               <value value="90204343"/>
            </identifier>
            <patient>
               <reference value="value/new"/>
            </patient>
            <relationship>
               <extension url="http://myurl4">
                  <valueCodeableConcept>
                     <coding>
                        <system value="http://myurl5"/>
                        <code value="abc"/>
                        <display value="value22222"/>
                     </coding>
                     <text value="value22222"/>
                  </valueCodeableConcept>
               </extension>
            </relationship>
            <name>
               <family value="ABC"/>
               <given value="TEST"/>
               <given value="JON"/>
            </name>
            <gender value="male"/>
            <birthDate value="1990-02-17"/>
         </user>
      </resource>
      <search>
         <mode value="123yyy"/>
      </search>
   </entry>
</Resource>
```

Comment: please note that in future I expect you to simplify the JSON or XML example to the minimal possible instead of just "dumping your homework" here. I hope that is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the XML is in the variable `response`:

```
# the first 2 lines are un-necessary, as all the
# XPath assertions start with /Resource
* json asJson = response
* match asJson contains { Resource: '#present' }
* match /Resource/type/@value == 'type1'
* match /Resource/valueTotal/@value == '7'
* match /Resource/entry[1]/url/@value == 'https://myurl1'
* match /Resource/entry[1]/resource/user/identifier/type/coding/code/@value == 'CC'
```

Please brush up on XML and XPath if needed: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#advanced-xpath

Comment: Awesome thanks alot. Yes, this is our first XML API ever so will learn from the shared link. Thanks Peter